# Wrong post date shown (wordpress)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

So, on a `first.php`, I have `<?php echo get_the_date('',$post->id); ?>` to show the post date which, for example, shows "2 days ago."

Using the ajax, I am getting the `post_id` of the post via `$_REQUEST['next_post']` then parsing it onto `second.php`

For the same post, I am using `<?php echo get_the_date('',$_REQUEST['next_post']); ?>` to get the date.

But the date simply shows as "46 years ago."

I am not sure why the date for the same post is different. Actually any posts loaded via ajax shows `46 years ago` as the post publish date.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Not without showing us some code, please show us your AJAX call and where you calculate the `next_post` value :)

Comment: There might be an issue with the post_id that you're sending with your AJAX call

Comment: if you're going to ask questions about Wordpress-specific functions, make sure you tag it appropriately. I had no idea what `get_the_date` was.

Comment: Had you monitor ,you are getting appropriate data by $_REQUEST['next_post'] ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_REQUEST['next_post']` is probably empty. get_the_date uses unix time stamps that count seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00.` Since you are posting null or 0 to get_the_date it will correctly display 46 years ago. Make sure `$_REQUEST['next_post']` is set in the request header. You can use the chrome web tools to check if it is. `Press ctrl + shift + j` and select the network tab. There you can see your requests with all request data.

Comment: Also if you want better help please post the code setting the $_REQUEST header.

Comment: Yours actually helped. Thank you! =)